# How can you explain the shape of the three lepton invariant mass plot in the case of proton-proton collisions

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics

I'm looking for events where a W and a Z boson is produced from the collision of two protons, with backgrounds coming from top-antitop production, production of 2 Z bosons and Drell-Yann processes (production of 1 Z boson). Selections have been made to reduce these backgrounds.

Plotted here is the invariant mass of the three lepton system.

[image: Three lepton invariant mass distribution]

What is the reason there is such a steep increase around 120 GeV? No selections I've made should specifically induce this behaviour, yet I can't really explain it. This feature is prominent in all components, signal and background. The only difference is that for ttbar and DY the peak and the steep increase coincide, while for the other components the steap increase comes first and then there's a peak.
Here's the same plot, unstacked:

[image: Three lepton invariant mass distribution unstacked]

Comment: That is why monte carlo is superinposed in plots of such plots. If the fit is good the why is in the physics generators used in the monte carlo.